# draw part of bitmap c++ builder

Tags: bitmap, c++builder, region

It's must not be hard to draw only specified form of bitmap, however I can't understand why that code doesn't work(I saw it in some delphi examples):

```
Graphics::TBitmap* bmp;

void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject* Sender)
{
    bmp = new Graphics::TBitmap();
    bmp->Width = 300;
    bmp->Height = 300;
    bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(0, 0, 300, 300);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject* Sender)
{
    HRGN rgn = CreateRectRgn(10, 10, 30, 30);
    if(SelectClipRgn(bmp->Handle, rgn) == ERROR) ShowMessage("Error");
    Canvas->Draw(0, 0, bmp);
}
```

So bitmap is drawn in usual way. In MSDN ERROR flag is explained as "previous clipping region is unaffected". Should device be configured first or should previous region be deleted? Is it right way to accomplish this task. I would use SetWindowRgn on TImage containing this bitmap, but TImage is not a window, therefore doesn't have Handle. Please, help me to find out what is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure with the `bmp->Handle` property ? Shouldn't that be rather `bmp->Canvas->Handle` passed to the `SelectClipRgn` function ?

Comment: no error is shown, but no bitmap is not "cropped"

Answer (score 1):

Just use `CopyRect`, a method of `Canvas`.

For example, create a button called Button2 and insert the following code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    //dimensions of real image: 300x300

    //clipping a region
    //dimension: 200x200
    //offset (x,y): (10,10)
    int xOff = 10;
    int yOff = 10;
    int widthOfRegion = 200;
    int heightOfRegion = 200;

    //printing the clipped region
    //dimension: 200x200
    //offset (x,y): (305,0) -> to do not overwrite image drawn by button1
    int xOff2 = 305;
    int yOff2 = 0;
    int widthOfRegion2 = 200;
    int heightOfRegion2 = 200;

    Canvas->CopyRect(
        //first rect is destination
        TRect(xOff2, yOff2, xOff2 + widthOfRegion2, yOff2 + heightOfRegion2)
        //second is canvas of source
        ,bmp->Canvas
        //third is rect of source that you want to copy
        ,TRect(xOff, yOff, xOff + widthOfRegion, yOff + heightOfRegion)
    );
}
```

So the result is below, after running and pressing Button1 and Button2:
[image: XD]

Tip: You can zoom in or out the clipped region changing width and height of region 2 :)

Source: http://www.borlandtalk.com/how-to-use-selectcliprgn-vt11696.html